# How I can add these two variable which have Multiple values in DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Here and Two Variable Store Two tables Data Now I want to Add these tables in to DataTable through Foreach Loop ?

```
    var meterData = MeterTable(startDateTime, endDateTime);
    var levelData = LevelTable(startDateTime, endDateTime);

      var dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Columns.Add("Meter", typeof(string));
                dataTable.Columns.Add("Volume", typeof(int));
                dataTable.Columns.Add("OpeningBalance", typeof(int));
                dataTable.Columns.Add("IN", typeof(int));
                dataTable.Columns.Add("Transfer", typeof(int));
                dataTable.Columns.Add("OUT", typeof(int));
                dataTable.Columns.Add("ClosingBalance", typeof(int));
   // how Onward i have not any idea ?
```

Comment: Add 4 columns : Meter Table Start, Meter Table End, Level Table Start, Level Table End.  Otherwise, use KeyValuePair<DateTime,DateTime> as column type.

Comment: @jdweng I have no idea how i can Add Rows Through Foreach loop ?

Comment: You are adding columns not rows.  Then you need to go back and add data to the new columns.  Where is the source of the data you are using?  Is it a list or some other object.

Comment: @jdweng its DataTable Stores in Two variables

Comment: It may very simple depending on format for  meterData and levelData.  Try             DataTable dt = meterData.CopyToDataTable();

Comment: @jdweng yeah but how can i use foreach loop to add rows in DataTable?

Comment: Like the other answers dataTable.Rows.Add();  You need to clarify more if you stillhave issues.  We do not know the format of your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all columns from each table you can do this:

```
var newTable = new DataTable();
//Copy the meter table into your new table
newTable = meterData.Copy();
//Use .Merge to merge in the level table
newTable.Merge(levelData);
```

If you want to add new rows, you create a datarow and add it to the datatable:

```
// Create new DataRow objects and add to DataTable.    
for(int i = 0; i < someNumberOfRows; i++)
{
    row = newTable.NewRow();
    row["column1"] = i;
    row["column2"] = "item " + i.ToString();
    newTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

If you need to use foreach, I'm assuming you want to iterate the rows in your 2 tables:

```
foreach(DataRow r in meterData.Rows)
{
   row = newTable.NewRow();
   row["someColumn"] = r["someColumn"];
   row["someOtherColumn"] = r["someOtherColumn"];
   newTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `new row` through `foreach` loop like this

```
  var dataTable = new DataTable();
  dataTable.Columns.Add("Meter", typeof(string));
  dataTable.Columns.Add("Volume", typeof(int));

foreach (var items in Source) //source is the where you want to loop
{
DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
row["Meter"] = "meter"; 
//you can access value of source items through item.NameofTargetField like items.meter  
row["Volume"] = 11;
dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```